# $L^p$ is reflexive for $1<p<2$, Brezis proof

Tags: lp-spaces, isometry, reflexive-space

Theorem 4.10 [pages 95-97] of [Brezis](http://www.math.utoronto.ca/almut/Brezis.pdf) proves that $L^p$ is reflexive for $p\in(1,\infty)$.
The last statement of the proof says that since $T(L^p)$ is reflexive, with $T$ being an isometry, so is $L^p$. Why is it true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if $E, \ F$ are isomorphic normed vector spaces, then
$F$ is reflexive $\Leftrightarrow$ $E$ is reflexive. Since $T$ is an isomorphism (onto $T(L^p)$), it follows that $L^p$ is reflexive.

Comment: Thank you! After some more digging I found your statement, it is mentioned in a footnote at page 71 of Brezis and it's not difficult to prove.